# Is there a semisimple $\mathbf{Q}_\ell$-representation of $G_F$ ramified at an infinite set of places?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, galois-representations

See http://math.uni.lu/~wiese/galois/Boeckle-Luxemburg-Notes.pdf, Theorem 1.4(a): Is there an example of a semisimple $\mathbf{Q}_\ell$-representation $V$ of $G_F$ ($F$ a global field) ramified at a set $S$ of places where $S$ is *not finite* (for every $\dim{V} \geq 1$)?

Comment: @Timo: I've added a tag and would also urge you to incorporate your own "answer" into an edited question to avoid confusion and focus the question better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that for $\dim{V} = 1$, there is no such representation http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/KretMaster.pdf p. 10.

Comment: The link seems to be https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/science/mi/scripties/kretmaster.pdf

Answer (score 6):

In the case $\dim V=2$, my advisor Ravi Ramakrishna has shown in his paper *Infinitely ramified Galois representations* (Ann. Math. **151**) that there are surjective representations $\rho\colon G_\mathbf{Q}\to \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ ramified at infinitely many primes.